# PHP Redirect Same Address Different Port

Tags: php, redirect

Right now I have this:

```
header("Refresh: 0; url=http://192.168.100.100:10500/redirect2.php");
```

How can I do the same redirect but without writing address, only port? Both files are in the same folder on the same server.

The thing is that I don't know the address that will be used to access this server (private or public).

Comment: why not just get the server address ? (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: typically I see it as `header("Location: http://192.168.100.100:10500/redirect2.php"); ` will this not work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the superglobal `$_SERVER` array, `Location` header and `exit;`

```
$port = '10500';
header('Location: '
    . ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http')
    . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . ':' . $port
    . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit;
```

Comment: thanks for making this work universally, I love copy paste.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's be useful for someone, isHttps() function can detect SSL.

```
function isHttps() {
      return
        (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off')
        || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443;
    }

$destinationPort = '10500';

$schema = isHttps() ? "https" : "http";
$schema .= "://";
header('Location: ' . $schema . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . ':' . $port
    . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

exit;
```