# Redirecting from one port to another using php

Tags: php, html

I have a Nodejs game at `localhost:8000/index.html` and my website is at `localhost:80`. How do I redirect from port 80 to 8000 using PHP?

```
header("Location: localhost:8000/index.html");
```

Comment: You need to add the scheme (`http://` or `https://` if you're running SSL) before the URL, or it will be treated as a relative path (appending it to the current URL).

Comment: thank you @MagnusEriksson , this worked quite well for me

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here:

[PHP Redirect Same Address Different Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308006/php-redirect-same-address-different-port)

The advantage of this is that it's dynamic. That means if you once happen to have another url than localhost this would also work.